# What strategies exist for handling/resolving ambiguity in parsers?

Tags: context-free, parsers

I define a *parser* as a context-free grammar with semantic actions for each production. It is not defined in what order the semantic actions run, just that the semantic actions of the non-terminals in a production run before itself does.

E.g. a (very) simple arithmetic language:

```
S -> E        { print(nt[0]) }
E -> E '+' P  { nt[0] + nt[1] }
E -> P        { nt[0] }
P -> P '*' X  { nt[0] * nt[1] }
P -> X        { nt[0] }
X -> N '^' X  { nt[0] ^ nt[1] }
X -> N        { nt[0] }
N -> N D      { 10*nt[0] + nt[1] }
N -> D        { nt[0] }
D -> '0'      { 0 }
...
D -> '9'      { 9 }
```

The concept of semantic actions are (to me) a clear way of turning a grammar into an actionable concept that explains that while two grammars might define the same *language*, they might not be equivalent.

This is why deterministic parsing (e.g. LL(1) or LR(1)) is unattractive to me, as you end up massaging your grammar to the wishes of the parser generator you're using.

As an example, if you use an unrestricted parser such as an Earley parser you can forget about having to massage your grammar into the requirements of whatever parser generator you're using and instead use the full behavior of the grammar. `E -> E '+' P` is left-associative and `X -> N '^' X` is right-associative, something that you can only express as such if you can use both right and left recursion.

However, if you give up deterministic parsing then CFGs can be ambiguous, so the above concept is still incomplete to me. Some people are interested in all ambiguous parses (e.g. natural language), but I am interested in *augmenting* a CFG parser as above in a way that *resolves* ambiguity.

What methods and techniques exist for augmenting an ambiguous grammar with additional info (which might already exist, e.g. the order in which productions are defined) or routines that allow ambiguous parses to be resolved/clarified to a unique unambiguous parse?

Comment: Just as a side issue: LR parsers handle both left- and right-recursive productions just fine, although right recursion requires more temporary storage. It's really not a big deal. (And an Earley parser will use more temporary storage than an LR(1) parsers parsing a completely right-recursive grammar.)

Comment: @rici I am aware, it was just an example of something that $LL(1)$ parsers or PEG parsers can't handle and require you to change the semantics of your grammar. With $LR(1)$ you have the dreaded reduce/reduce or shift/reduce conflicts. An Earley parser will always use more memory AFAIK (because it is a chart parser), but _"A general context-free parsing algorithm running in linear time on every LR(k) grammar without using lookahead"_ does describe an optimization for Earley parsers that make sure it runs in linear time and memory for any $LR(k)$ grammar.

Comment: So what parsing algorithm has trouble with right recursion? I get your point, but I think it's important to understand the real issues. Ambiguity needs to be addressed by making the grammar non-ambiguous, not because of the requirements of a parser generator, but because of the requirements of programmers who need to know what their programs mean. The annoyance with LR(1) is the 1, not the LR. Most "dreaded" conflicts are the result of grammar bugs, but sometimes it makes sense to design a syntax which requires more lookahead...

Comment: ... and those are the cases in which my current advice is to find a GLR/GLL parser generator, because those will work without having to modify or annotate the grammar. I honestly see little value in non-deterministic grammars for languages intended for precise descriptions (unlike, say, human languages).

Comment: My goal is to *write* a parser generator that can handle ambiguity internally, but with mechanics to handle that ambiguity. _"Ambiguity needs to be addressed by making the grammar non-ambiguous"_ <citation needed>. I'm exactly interested in approaches that address ambiguity not by changing the grammar, but by deciding on ambiguity after the parse has completed (e.g. precedence of rules). My question is asking for those approaches - which exist? Also a perfectly reasonable non-LR(k) language is a language that allows the user to escape quotes by repeating the start/end quote: `"""test"ing"""`.

Comment: This isn't wikipedia. I'm not restricted to quoting other people. That's my sincere belief and I stand by it. I even offered the key reason for my belief: that a syntax which is ambiguous for a parser is ambiguous for a human. It's very important (to me) that my programs say what I think they say, and that people who read my programs understand what they mean. It's not a coincidence that it's common for style guides to recommend, for example, unnecessary parentheses in C programs in order to avoid relying on the subtly unambiguous syntax....

Comment: ...In short, it's my belief that a grammar is a part of the documentation for a programming language, and that it should not only be unambiguous but clearly unambiguous for a human reader. You are allowed to disagree with that judgement, too, but if you're going to do so, I'd ask that you offer a counter-argument, not a meme.

Comment: Finally: if you mean by your comment about raw quotes something like C++'s raw-quote syntax, that's not just not LR(k), but also not context-free (aside from the limitation of quote strings to 16 characters which makes it technically but not practically context-free). If you mean Python style one-quote or three, that's certainly LR(k) which means that an LR(1) grammar exists, although most of us would prefer the grammar with a larger k. In any event, it's completely unambiguous.

Comment: @rici How is it not context-free? $S \to `` S " \mid [any] S \mid \lambda$ would work, no? It might be *ambiguous*, e.g. `""test"" + ""ing""` could be two strings with a `+` between them or one long string, but that could be resolved to always go towards the shortest match possible *with disambiguation rules*.

Comment: It's not so much that it's ambiguous: it's that it recognises sentences which are not (supposed to be) part of the language. What you are thinking of as *disambiguation* is (if I understand your intention correctly) actually supposed to eliminate some parses *even if they were the only valid parse*.  Eg., extending your example, do you really expect `""test"" + 3a + ""ing""` to be a single string only because the stuff in between the two shorter strings contains a syntax error? That might prove to be extremely surprising to a programmer....

Comment: .Now, it's true that "terminates at the first matching delimiter" is a non-context-free provision which humans can understand perfectly, as is, for example, "you must declare a variable before you use it". But those aren't really questions of ambiguity. Trying to find a usable formalism for context-sensitive constructions like those is a pretty long-standing as-yet-unresolved CS problem.

Comment: The only formalisms I'm aware of are the ones used to try to define operator precedence, which I'm sure you are aware of and which I suspect you don't find particularly interesting. Precedence declarations do disambiguate a grammar, but mostly in cases where it would have been pretty easy to write an unambiguous grammar in the first place. Anyway, good luck. I'll look forward to seeing your results.